# How to replace numbers in selected columns that falls in certain value python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do you replace numbers with np.nan in selected columns if the number falls in between 2 ranges?

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 | 9 | 7 |
| 5 | 3 | 6 | 7 |

select columns B & C replace numbers if number is <=5 and >=7

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | NaN | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | 7 |
| 5 | NaN | 6 | 7 |

Comment: I'm assuming this is a pandas question and you are dealing with DataFrames?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: I also assume, you want to replace values strictly lower than 5 (given the provided output)

Comment: lower or equal to  5 and bigger  or equal to  7 for column b & c only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a boolean mask for in place modification ([boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)):

```
cols = ['B', 'C']
m = (df[cols].gt(7)|df[cols].lt(5)).reindex(columns=df.columns, fill_value=False)

df[m] = np.nan
```

If you need a copy:

```
cols = ['B', 'C']
out = df.mask((df[cols].gt(7)|df[cols].lt(5))
              .reindex(columns=df.columns, fill_value=False))
```

Output:

```
   A   B    C  D
0  2 NaN  5.0  7
1  2 NaN  NaN  7
2  5 NaN  6.0  7
```

Intermediates:

```
(df[cols].gt(7)|df[cols].lt(5))

      B      C
0  True  False
1  True   True
2  True  False

(df[cols].gt(7)|df[cols].lt(5)).reindex(columns=df.columns, fill_value=False)

       A     B      C      D
0  False  True  False  False
1  False  True   True  False
2  False  True  False  False
```

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to add `cols = ['B', 'C']`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign back to filtered columns with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
cols = ['B', 'C']

df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].gt(7) | df[cols].lt(5))
print (df)
   A   B    C  D
0  2 NaN  5.0  7
1  2 NaN  NaN  7
2  5 NaN  6.0  7
```

Or with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
cols = ['B', 'C']

df[cols] = np.where(df[cols].gt(7) | df[cols].lt(5), np.nan, df[cols])
print (df)
   A   B    C  D
0  2 NaN  5.0  7
1  2 NaN  NaN  7
2  5 NaN  6.0  7
```